What are the differences between the Silk browser environment and the Amazon APL web environment?
I am using a custom Alex skill to display a web page on an Amazon Echo Show 5.  The skill uses the APL OpenURL command to open the web page in an APL document. The page does not display properly using the skill, but works fine when entered directly in the Silk browser on the same device.
Question: what are the significant differences between the browser environment provided by the Silk browser and the APL OpenUrl command, that could affect how a document is displayed?
Relevant differences could include variations in the subset of HTML, CSS or JavaScript features supported by Silk or the OpenURL environment, the types of resource they are allowed to retrieve, or whether they identify themselves differently to client-side JavaScript code, or to the HTTP server.  References to any documentation highlighting these differences would be welcome. (I've Googled unsuccessfully, the OpenURL documentation linked above wasn't helpful).
Background
For context, the web page I am trying to load is the external URL for my Home Assistant instance. The custom skill works, in that it connects to the my server and displays a logo; but it doesn't get as far as displaying the log-on screen; nothing is shown in the Home Assistant logs. However, the same URL loads fine when entered directly into the Silk browser on the same Echo Show 5 device (or other browsers on other types of device). This makes it hard to debug (e.g. the problem doesn't appear when using the Alexa Developer Console).  Obviously the hardware isn't the issue, as it works in Silk. My assumption is that the problem is caused by something in the web page code: either it is using some feature that is not supported in the APL environment, or it detects the APL environment differently to the Silk environment, and serves up broken code as a result. I'm asking the question so that I can get an idea of where to start trial-and-error debugging on the content of the web page.
